# Facebook c# sdk - how to make "Share" link show up when publishing post

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook C# SDK in order to post content on a profile's wall.  Whatever gets posted to the wall does not include the "Share" link.  It has "Like" and "Comment," but not "Share."

Question: how to I make that Share link show up?  Thanks!

Some code...

```
string profileId = "XYZ";
string accessToken = "abc"; // I already know how to get accessToken

FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
messagePost.picture = "http://pic.com/pic.png";
messagePost.link = "http://www.examplearticle.com";
messagePost.name = "name goes here";
messagePost.description = "description goes here";

var result = client.Post(string.Format("/{0}/feed", profileId), messagePost);
```

Is there something like messagePost.enableShare = "true", or messagePost.type = "shareableLink" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
var result = client.Post(string.Format("/{0}/links", profileId), messagePost);
```

By using "/links" instead of "/feed," the Share link shows up.